# How to catch a value from a matrix using a progressive index?

Tags: c#, .net, list, matrix

Let say I have this Matrix:

```
public static List<List<string>> WallPattern1550 = new List<List<string>>
{ 
    new List<string> { "3", "2", "1", "1", "2" },
    new List<string> { "1", "2", "2" },
    new List<string> { "2", "1", "2" },
    new List<string> { "2", "2", "1" },
    new List<string> { "2", "1", "1", "1" },
    new List<string> { "1", "2", "1", "1" },
    new List<string> { "1", "1", "2", "1" },
    new List<string> { "1", "1", "1", "2" }
};
```

and I quickly want the 16° value (the index I meant), which is `1` (WallPattern1550[3][1]), how can I do it?

How can I translate that 16 to 3,1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can be done like this:

```
WallPattern1550.SelectMany(x => x).Skip(15).First();
```

But personally I would use an extension method for that:

```
public static T GetValueAt<T>(this List<List<T>> source, int index)
{
     int counter = 0;
     foreach(var list in source)
        foreach (var x in list)
        {
             counter++;
             if (counter == index) return x;
        }

     return default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
var value = WallPattern1550.GetValueAt(16);
```

If you want to get indices here is another extension method that you can use:

```
public static void FindCoordinates<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source, int count, out int x, out int y)
{
     x = 0;
     y = 0;
     int counter = 0;

     foreach (var list in source)
     {
         y = 0;
         foreach (var z in list)
         {
              if (counter == count) break;
              y++;
              counter++;
         }
         if (counter == count) break;
         x++;
     }    
}
```

Usage:

```
int x, y;
WallPattern1550.FindCoordinates(16,out x, out y); // x = 4, y = 2
```

Comment: Assuming you're looking for the value `1`, not the indexes `3, 1`. The question says the latter, but it seems reasonable to think he really wants the former.

Comment: yeah, I just focused to get sixteenth element. but `16` corresponds `[4][2] ` am I wrong or is that a typo?